# How to use XMLRPC in Joomla 3.X

Tags: joomla3.0, xml-rpc

I am lost with this and I need help. A point where start. I have been reading other stackoverflow questions but they are all about Joomla 1.5 whose XMLRPC is deprecated. i am working with Joomla! 3.45

I have also read [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Xml-rpc) but it does not explain a thing about how to deal with the request. I have download the example at the end of the page but when I try to install it and see how it works, I get a JInstaller: :Install: Can't find Joomla XML setup file expection.

Could somebody help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search extensions.joomla.org there is an an extension already for this. you can read the PHP code for that